# Access a PLESK website before propagation?

Tags: domains, dns, testing, plesk

My web host uses Plesk and I want to know if there is anyway to access and view a website (with PHP and other processes being functional) without propagation of the domain name?

I have found countless forums on this but they are all pretty old (circa 01-04) and involve either tricking your localhost or SSH commands and some even result in terrible security risks.

I would like to access a web page directory through a browser and see it's contents while having the PHP processes carry out... *before* I propagate it's potential domain name. People claim this is pointless but during a site migration why on earth would you not test a site before propagating it?

I'm looking for something similar to what cPanel offers i.e. `http://IP.ADDRESS./~mydomain.com`

The only solution I could think of is storing the site in a new directory of an already functional site and then setting up databases and testing the site once it's complete.

Once tested and working I should be easily be able to migrate the files to the "new" domain name's root directory and just setup a new databases and then propagate the domain name.

I can't believe that Plesk V10+ still does not have a site preview method that includes PHP, JS, and Flash ability.

Comment: I don't know about PLESK. But I DO know that you can set the '(test-)site' as the first one in the vhosts in apache. Which makes  the site avialable through the IP. Another thing you could do is: If you already have a DNS record pointing to that machine use a subdomain of it to test it before you set the DNS to test it.

Comment: I don't want to be trivial, but did you ask to the hoster that sold you the PLESK plan? And next time stick to cPanel (just kidding!) :)

Comment: Yea, I asked them.  They claimed it wasn't possible.  I've seen many forums to prove that wrong, but as I stated before, they often include risky methods or tricking the local host.  I have no interest in either.

Comment: Plesk used to use the IP/~domain.tld up till about v6 or 7 that worked anyway..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have full functioning site preview starting from Plesk 10.4 (PHP, Javascript and whatever else you need). It needs to be enabled on the server - so if in shared hosting, you will depend on you hosting provider. Checkout ["Setting up Website Preview"](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.4/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/70219.htm) for details. You will need some DNS zone for previews though...

You may also be interested in ["staging sites"](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.4.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/plesk-control-panel-user-guide/66505.htm) - temporary site to see how it works before publishing.

PS unfortunately as a new user I cannot post more links, but you can find more in Plesk documentation by "preview" keyword

Comment: Yea I got the updgrade a few days after I asked this question.  Can't believe it took them 10 versions to add that feature, and everyone's looking at me like I'm crazy when I ask "How can I test the site before it's launched?" lol

Answer (score 0):

Edit your HOSTS file

```
ip.ip.ip.ip      domain.com
190.190.190.190  domain.com
```

has the added advantage that no one else can see the site / index it pre launch